# How to create time reports by user/project in Phabricator Phrequent

Tags: reporting, phabricator, time-tracking

Is there a way to create a custom reporting system under the Phrequent section in Phabricator?

In the Maniphest app there is a report feature. However, it only counts total number of task by person or project. My organization still requires total time spent on a project and task.

Inside Phrequent you can already sort by user, however, I need one step further total time spent on a task by user or project. Currently it requires a manual process of totaling each time entry per task by hand.

Answer (score 2):

This is not "yet" a feature and there is no implemented way of doing it right now.
Phrequent is still in its early stage of development and a lot of work remains on it.

The tracking per project is definitely a must feature and is being logged here:
https://secure.phabricator.com/T4853

Finally, the current focus for Phabricator right now seems to be the CI part (Harbormaster and Drydock) so the roadmap does not mention incoming work in the short term:
https://secure.phabricator.com/w/roadmap/
but only in the long term:
https://secure.phabricator.com/w/starmap/

On a side note, I considered using phrequent but I believe it's too far from being production ready right now so using other time tracking system seems to be the only viable solution.

Comment: Thomas, thank you for your reply. I was afraid of this. Do you have any recommendations as to a good time tracking application that has a plugin with Phabricator? I did notice Asana works with Phab, but I was really hoping to find an open source application.

Comment: I guess time tracking with Asana comes with 3rd party like Harvest and Everhour. I'm not sure changing your whole issue/task platform with asana just to have one of its tool is reasonable (unless you are in need of actual Asana features).

Comment: And now that I think about it, if your team uses a tool like Slack, it integrates with many app including some time-tracking. Most of the Chat system got a Hubot integration which integrates with nearly anything, definitely needs some hard set-up but it's a pretty cool tool when used right.